# Как модернизировать Str::slug в laravel

Tags: laravel

Возможно ли модернизировать `Str::slug в laravel`?
Изначально он удаляет все `,` и `.`, а мне в определенном месте нужно разрешить использование `,.`
Нашел класс `Str` по адресу `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Str`
И функцию `slug`, подправил как мне нужно(Добавил $field):

```
    public static function slug($title, $separator = '-', $language = 'en', $field = false)
    {
        $title = $language ? static::ascii($title, $language) : $title;

        // Convert all dashes/underscores into separator
        $flip = $separator === '-' ? '_' : '-';

        $title = preg_replace('!['.preg_quote($flip).']+!u', $separator, $title);

        // Replace @ with the word 'at'
        $title = str_replace('@', $separator.'at'.$separator, $title);

        if($field) {
            $title = str_replace(',', '.', $title);
            $title = static::lower($title);
        } else {
            // Remove all characters that are not the separator, letters, numbers, or whitespace.
            $title = preg_replace('![^'.preg_quote($separator).'\pL\pN\s]+!u', '', static::lower($title));
        }

        // Replace all separator characters and whitespace by a single separator
        $title = preg_replace('!['.preg_quote($separator).'\s]+!u', $separator, $title);

        return trim($title, $separator);
    }
```

И вызываю `Str::slug('1,2.4', '-', 'en', 1);` - Все работает

Но получается, что при обновлении композера все может потерятся,и при переносе проекта, придется всегда копировать папку vendro.

Думал о переносе `slug` в свой класс, если я правильно понял, то там все связанно и придется весь класс `Str` переносить к себе

Может есть более простой способ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласен с автором вопроса: менять код в папках `vendor` и `node_modules` - не лучшая затея. Хотя, чего греха таить, порой пока дождешься обновок )

Довольно распространенной практикой является следующий путь. Создается файл в директории - **app\Support\helpers.php**, в котором определяются пользовательские функции. В вашем случае его содержание может быть примерно следующим:

```
<?php

if (! function_exists('string_slug')) {
  /**
   * Generate a URL friendly "slug" from a given string.
   * ...
   * @return string
   */
  function string_slug(...)
  {
    // Тут код функции.
  }
}
```

Далее этот файл необходимо зарегистрировать в `composer.json`, добавив в поле *autoload*

```
...
  "autoload": {
    ...
    "files": [
      "app/Support/helpers.php"
    ]
  }
...
```

И обновить автозагрузчик, выполнив команду `composer dump-autoload -o`. Теперь эта функция `string_slug(...)` будет доступна в вашем проекте: хоть в моделях, хоть в шаблонах.