# Laravel Localization | Локализация, как установить значение по умолчанию?

Tags: laravel, локализация

Как установить значение по умолчанию если запись не найдена.

Имеется **lang.php**

```
<?php

return [
    'name' => [
        'to' => 'do',
        'e' => 'tc',
        'stack' => 'overflow',
    ]
];
```

Делаю

```
__('lang.name.stack')
// output: overflow
```

Если не найден

```
__('lang.name.empty')
// output: lang.name.empty
```

Как установить дефолтное значение, чтобы подставляло не `lang.name.empty` ?

Comment: Только предварительной проверкой `trans()->has($string) ? trans($string) : $default`

Comment: Вот так обычно регистрируют https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/961891/256824

Comment: Ответ напишите, интересно же как вы решили данный вопрос )

Comment: @РустамГимранов я пока-что опустил данный вопрос, не решал проблему эту